# Can't get CassandraTableScanRDD with akka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, akka, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to make an API Rest with Akka. One of the entry point will return data from my Cassandra Database. So I can get my CassandraTableScanRDD like that :

```scala
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark Cassandra")
    .config("spark.cores.max", "5")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/tmp")
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val connector = CassandraConnector.apply(spark.sparkContext.getConf)
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val temp = sc.cassandraTable("scala_firemen", "firemen")
  
  temp.foreach(println)
```

And with this code I can get all the data I need. But once I add my Akka code I can no more print/access to the data. Even if I roll back and delete the Akka code I still code the same error which is :

> [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> [error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> [error] at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>
> [error] at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1367)
>
> [error] at main$.delayedEndpoint$main$1(Server.scala:34)
>
> [error] at main$delayedInit$body.apply(Server.scala:15)
>
> ...
>
> ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
>
> ...
>
> ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
>
> ...
>
> ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread SparkListenerBus
>
> ...

When I recreate a project the code works again so I suspect that I need to clean something after the deletion of the Akka code to works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figure it out that I can't have the `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json"` dependency with the all the spark dependencies like :

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.1",
"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.10"
```

Answer (score 2):

RDD are designed to be used with Spark, and it makes no sense to use it in the `StreamingContext` at all...

For your Akka application you need to [Java driver directly](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/), and even in this case, you don't need to perform full scan of data - fast access to the data is provided only when you have a least partition key... If you still need to perform full scan, then it's better to use something like [this](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java) - Spark uses similar approach for data scan, but you won't need to link all its libraries.

I suggest that you get some introduction into how Cassandra works - for example, via [courses on DataStax Academy](http://academy.datastax.com/) - they will explain how you can access to the data, etc.

Comment: Yes but what I don't understand is that everything works but once i got an error even if I roll back i still got this error. Thanks, I will the courses !

Comment: I paste the wrong code, I was using the sparkContext (Edited)